# Can I totally skip a pass of a ShaderLab shader?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I want to totally skip a pass of a shader depending on a Property of the inspector in Unity, such as this: (Keep in mind this won't compile)

```
Shader "Name"
{
Properties
{
    [Toggle(STUFF_ON)] _StuffOn("Stuff On", Float) = 1
}
SubShader
{
    #if STUFF_ON
    Pass
    {
        [...]
    }
    #endif
    Pass
    {
        [...]
    }
}
}
```

I already looked for Toggles (as shown in the example), pragma shader_feature and multi_compile, but all of them would only let me use the directive *inside* the pass itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to duplicate the shader, but without the pass you want to skip. Then just swap between as needed.

For reference here is an example of how you could swap a shader within a monobehaviour:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class ShaderSwapExample : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        Shader TransDiffuseShader = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");

        if (TransDiffuseShader != null)
        {
            Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderer.material.shader = TransDiffuseShader;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more information about swapping shaders [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html)

Comment: I guess that should do, although I was looking for something that didn't imply duplicating code, since maintenance is an issue then. The other solution I found is to simply render float4(0,0,0,0) as output if the feature is disabled.

Comment: This solution is very expensive if you are going to use it with hundreds of objects.

Comment: Depends what you are after @Sergey. If you are using hundreds of objects it's potentional worthwhile updating the shader of the specific material and/or using renderer.sharedMaterial.

If the adapatablity is key, it's best to look at more complex shaders such as the Unity default shaders, which can change the passes it uses on the fly. Almost certain this will require a GPU upload on the hardware side.

Personally I think having shaders doing the minimum work and swapping between them based on requirements works well.